# Macro in QAT not referenced to saved workbook

Tags: macros, excel-2007

I have an excel template that has a macro button in the quick access toolbar (QAT). When I save the template as an Excel Macro Enabled Workbook, the button found in the QAT is linked back to the macro in the original template, not the macro found in the new file I just saved. Is there a way I can get the QAT toolbar in this new file to reference the macro in the saved file instead of original template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out finally. I needed to add it for the current document only, not all documents (default). Opposite of what I intuitively thought. It probably has something to do with how the macros are stored with each option.