# Make a ribbon button reference the macro in a new workbook instance rather than in the source template

Tags: vba, excel, templates, excel-2010

I have a macro-enabled Excel template which contains a ribbon button pointing to a macro sub.  The button assignment still points to the source template, however, instead of the sub in the new document.  If I create a document and then move or delete the template, I'm no longer able to use the button in the new document:

[image]

I've noticed that the ribbon button seems have the macro's source template path hard-coded, and there isn't any place I can find in ribbon customization UI to change it:

[image]

I'm certain this has been asked before, but I've tried a number of different ways of searching for it without coming up with anything.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392447/copy-a-worksheet-to-a-new-workbook-and-have-a-button-point-to-the-macro-in-the-n) which talks about a button on a form, not a ribbon, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317817/create-a-new-workbook-import-macro-and-assign-button) which seems to be generating "shapes" programmatically and assigning their action; neither of these two are relevant.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21437318/2704659) is the closest I've found, but whereas the QAT customization tab has the option for setting the target:

[image]

the ribbon customization tab does not have that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to look at using CustomUI. Check out Ron de Bruin's site for a wealth of information.

Comment: You mean modifying the open office XML?  I know how to do that, but that's the only option here?  I'm surprised.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the only option, just the easiest.

Comment: Assuming you have an editor.  I've done those modifications manually, which is painful.  Do you have a free editor you recommend?

Comment: Or I'll check out Ron de Bruin...

Comment: I usually use the CustomUI editor, but Andy Pope has a free add-in on his site you can use.

Comment: Thanks for your help.